# tensorflow memory SIGABRT

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, operating-system

https://github.com/YCG09/chinese_ocr
when i run this model, test the demo.py, i can't open chrome, only pycharm, otherwise the programs get the error of "segmentfault and core dump", then killed. if only pycharm was opened, program runs fine.
ubuntu 18.04, cuda9.0 cudnn7.0.5, tensorflow1.7.0, python2.7. Before this, i was using ubuntu 16.04, just fine that time and it will print allocates of XXX memory exceeds 10% memory of system, in ubuntu 18.04, no print and just kill the programs.
i am wondering if the problem comes from the ubuntu, the OS might limit the usage of memory.
this problem is a mystery, i'd appreciate very much for your kind answer!